# first row matching criteria, after first row matching other criteria

Tags: window-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do I find the first row that matches criteria and follows the first row to match other criteria? I can do it with a join easily enough, but wish to avoid a join (and thus, presumably, use window functions). I'm using Snowflake (but if you know an answer in another dialect, I can try to translate it). I haven't been able to figure out a way to do this without a join.

For clarity, suppose my data is

```
create table t (col1 varchar, col2 varchar, col3 varchar, row_number int) as
      select 'a', 'd' ,'r', 1
union select 'a', 'c', 'r', 2
union select 'b', 'd', 'r', 3
union select 'b', 'c', 's', 4
union select 'a', 'd', 's', 5
union select 'a', 'd', 'r', 6
```

Among rows with `col3='r'`, the first with `col2='c'` is 2, and the first *after that* with `col1='a'` is 6. I wish to pick out row 6 based on those criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snowflake offers very powerful [JavaScript user-defined table functions](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/udf-js-table-functions.html), that can be easily used here.

Here's the code...

Let's first create the data

```
create or replace table t (col1 varchar, col2 varchar, col3 varchar, row_number int)
as select * from values
        ('a', 'd' ,'r', 1),
        ('a', 'c', 'r', 2),
        ('b', 'd', 'r', 3),
        ('b', 'c', 's', 4),
        ('a', 'd', 's', 5),
        ('a', 'd', 'r', 6);
```

Then we introduce a table function that consumes rows containing `col1` and `col2`, and for each row returns a `MATCH` column containing `true/false` depending if it matches your predicate

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc (
        col1 varchar,
        col2 varchar)
RETURNS TABLE (MATCH boolean)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$
{
  seen: false,
  produced: false,
  processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
        let match = false;
        if (!this.seen && row.COL2 == "c") {       
          this.seen = true;       
        } else if (this.seen && !this.produced && row.COL1 == "a") {          
          this.produced = true;   
          match = true;
        }
        rowWriter.writeRow({MATCH: match});
   },
   initialize: function (argumentInfo, context) {
     this.seen = this.produced = false;
   }
}   
$$;
```

And then we use it, partitioning the data by `col3`, and making sure the rows are consumed along `row_number`:

```
select * from t,
        table(myfunc(col1, col2) over (partition by col3 order by row_number));

------+------+------+------------+-------+
 COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | ROW_NUMBER | MATCH |
------+------+------+------------+-------+
 b    | c    | s    | 4          | FALSE |
 a    | d    | s    | 5          | TRUE  |
 a    | d    | r    | 1          | FALSE |
 a    | c    | r    | 2          | FALSE |
 b    | d    | r    | 3          | FALSE |
 a    | d    | r    | 6          | TRUE  |
------+------+------+------------+-------+
```

If you need to, you can now simply filter on MATCH and you're done.

Naturally, you can express arbitrarily complex logic in a function like this.

Comment: Many thanks! I'd +1 if I could, but I've insufficient rep.

Comment: We use UDF's this way for stateful problems like this.. so I'll give you that +1

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim Good point about stateful UDFs. I didn't recommend them as here we have an ordering requirement in the input, and also UDFs are not guaranteed to maintain state between calls.

Comment: @MarcinZukowski the fact you are "solving" multi ordering constraints is "stateful"..

Where-as I agree the is the keeping of state (which can be used to avoid initializing large data objects for each row) which improves performance quite a large amount, which is I think is what you were getting at having not mentioning.